# Who originally conquered Jerusalem?

Tags: yerushalayim-jerusalem, shoftim--book-of

Of course we generally think that it was conquered by King David. But in Shoftim 1:8 it says that Jerusalem was captured by the tribe of Judah soon after the death of Joshua. So how do we understand this contradiction?

Answer (score 2):

[Shoftim 1:8](https://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/15809/showrashi/true#v8) says that they set the city on fire. However [Shoftim 1:9](http://mg.alhatorah.org/Full/Shofetim/1.9#e0n6) says that after setting it on fire, they left the city to fight the other Canaanites. They did not actually take it over.

> And afterward the children of Judah went down to fight against the
>   Canaanites; the inhabitants of the mountains, of the South, and of the
>   lowland.

[Shoftim 1:21](https://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/15809/showrashi/true#v21) shows that the part of the city under the Jebusites was left alone. As Rashi says:

> **the Jebusites that inhabited Jerusalem:** There was a section in Jerusalem called Jebuse, which was populated by the descendants of
>   Abimelech who were not driven out because of the oath [which Abraham
>   had sworn], until the coming of David. This was because his grandson
>   was still alive and Abraham had sworn [Gen. 21:23] to him, his son,
>   and grandson.

That is the section that remained until the time of David Hamelech. Also see Rashi on [Yehoshua 15:63](https://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/15799/showrashi/true#v63)

> As for the Jebusites the inhabitants of Jerusalem, the children of
>   Judah could not drive them out; but the Jebusites dwelt with the
>   children of Judah in Jerusalem to this day.

Rashi:

> **the children of Judah could not drive them out:** We learned in Sifrei : Rabbi
>   Joshua the son of Korha says: They really could, but
>   they were not permitted, because of the oath which Abraham had sworn
>   to Abimelech. Now these Jebusites were not of the Jebusite nation, but
>   the Tower of David which was in Jerusalem, was called Jebus, and the
>   inhabitants of that section were of the Philistines. And when the
>   children of Judah conquered Jerusalem, they did not drive out the
>   inhabitants of that section.

Comment: The split city theory doesn't make any historical sense, since there was only one water source.

Comment: It should be noted, that [Rashi on Devarim 12:17](https://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9976/showrashi/true#v17) (s.v. "לא תוכל", based on [Pirkei DeRabbi Eliezer 36](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Pirkei_DeRabbi_Eliezer.36.16?lang=bi&lang2=en)), says that the oath was made to the Hittites (rather than Abimelech the Philistine), as part of the exchange for the cave of Machpelah. There is also a [discussion about the contradiction](http://forum.otzar.org/viewtopic.php?t=20087) on Otzar HaHochma's forum.

Comment: Thanks for the information. @TamirEvan

Comment: See also https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/4679/how-did-the-sages-know-that-jerusalem-had-a-wall-in-the-times-of-joshua.

Comment: @DoubleAA per what do you say there was only one water source?

Comment: @Harel pok chazi